# Choosing a database for big data

Tags: database-design

Let's say I want to write a web service that stores home automation device readings such as thermostats, humidifiers, etc. The data would take the form of:

user_id | device_id | tag | value | timestamp

A user could have 5, 10, or 20 devices connected based on account type and readings could be taken at 1, 5, or 10 minute intervals based on account type. The service could record 10, 50, or 100 tags for each connected device.

This means I would theoretically need to support a batch insert of 2000 rows per user per minute.

Let's say I want to scale to 10,000 users. That means an upper limit of 20,000,000 rows inserted per user per minute. So 28 billion rows per day.

What kind of databases should I be considering to handle this kind of load and how would it scale? I'd especially be worried about storage space, I think it would need to make use of cloud storage.

Comment: What kind of queries are you going to be asking it?  Analytics, primary key lookups, etc

Comment: Analytics. Date range graphs of selected tag values.

Comment: I could probably limit the dataset to have 1,5, and 10 minute intervals for a 30 day period per customer. For data older than that, perhaps I can just save one row per tag per day with max/min/avg values.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard of a company which is doing this. They're using a Cassandra cluster with several nodes (in two data centers).

Answer (score 1):

I would ask you first how much money are you willing to spent for this ?

 I terms of number of rows stored in the database it all depends on your data type,length.. so you can figure out how much space you will need.
Now to answer your question and give you my database engine recommendation i would go for **HP Vertica** - by far the best choice for your project.
 **Why is HP Vertica the best choice :**

- 1- is much cheaper then Oracle or teradata or and DW - and does not
  require self appliance.- you can insstall it on any linux box.
- 2- it works in cluster so MMP(massive parallel processin) will be a
  great add in.
- 3- since you say you have alot of data - Vertica comes with build in
  capabilities to store encoded/compressed  data and as well query
  encoded data.
   Depending on the data type you might get up to 90%
  in storage gains.
- 4- i see you have a time window between data load:
- 5- Vertica scales out linearly and no need of down time, the nodes
  are shared nothing arch so is like plug and play basically- add the
  node re-balance the data and that's it the node will participate

  With Vertica you can load those 20.000.000 rows in no time using its load capabilities.
- Because of it internal structure Verica will handle big loads with
  ease.
- Working with Vertica is so easy it comes with SQL ANSI syntax , has
  some great build in functions that can help you deal with lots of big
  data problems.

More on how you can build a Vertica Cluster in like 10 min see this [link](http://www.aodba.com/main_tutorials.php?page=vertica&id_tit=22)  and as well this one [link2](http://www.aodba.com/main_articles_single.php?art=9999&page=vertica&id_tit=6) - both of this link will get to my website where i have wrote some articles on how to work with Vertica database.

Fell free to contact me if you need any guided help - i would gladly do, no charge what so ever , i just love this Vertica database .
**One more thing i don't represent in any way any HP or any HP re-seller.**
[image]